# Perseverance landing and the skycrane

Tags: mars, nasa, rovers, perseverance, skycrane

I have a question about the skycrane which helped Perseverance NASA landing. In the image below, why there is not something like fire at the mentioned exhausts (I don't know whether exhaust word is correct or not!) in the picture? Many thanks.
[image]

Comment: @Phiteros , many thanks for the reply. yes.

Comment: @Phiteros I think you recommended merging? If so I agree, and for the same reasons you'd stated.